# Can LMM or GLMM models handle negative values?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm

I am working on a set of correlated data. I am planning to apply LMM to my data, however my dependent variable has both positive and negative values. So, I was wondering if LMM or GLMM models can handle negative values?

Answer (score 1):

LMM (Linear Mixed Models) are linear models, and have no more problems with negative responses than linear regression has, that is, none. GLMM's (Generalized Linear Mixed Models) is a bigger class, extending glm's, some of them can handle negative responses, others not.

Just look at the glm you are extending with some random effects in the linear predictor.